# Printing array of char in java in matrix-like form

Tags: java

I am writing a program to display an array of `char` in rows and columns(see below). But, the output of my code right now is like so:

```
hhhhehehehelhelhelhellhellhell
```

What i want to display is this:

```
h e l l
o w o r
l d n e
w d a y
```

And here's my current code:

```
String str = "helloworldnewday"; 

  double length = Math.sqrt(str.length());
  int x = (int) length;

  char[] ch = new char[str.length()]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { 
    for (int j = 1; j< x; j++){
      ch[i] = str.charAt(i); 
      System.out.print(ch);
    } 
  }
```

I know my code is terrible because I just began learning. Can you guys tell me what's wrong with my code? I appreciate every answer. Thank you.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: It is unclear how that code is supposed to print multiple lines of text, when you never call `println()`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `j` when you never use it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `for` loop over all the characters of the `String`. Use the modulus operator (`%`) to check if you need to print a new line. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/yO8ogP).

```
String str = "helloworldnewday";
double length = Math.sqrt(str.length());
int x = (int) length;
for (int i = 0, len = str.length(); i < len; i++) {
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i) + " ");
    if (i % x == x - 1) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
h e l l 
o w o r 
l d n e 
w d a y
```